# From origin chord is drawn to the circle x^2 +y^2-2ax=0 . Find the locus of the centre of circle taking chord as diameter.

Tags: circles

From the origin, a chord is drawn to the circle $x^2 +y^2-2ax=0$. Find the locus of the centre of the circle taking that chord as diameter.

Taking the equation of the chord as $y=mx$, I have found the point of intersections of the chord and the circle as
$$(0,0) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \left(\frac{2a}{1+m^2} , \frac{2am}{1+m^2}\right).$$

If I take the center as $(h,k)$, then $h=\frac{a}{1+m^2}$ ,  $k= \frac{am}{1+m^2}$

I am having some trouble with elimination of $m$.

Comment: Centre is already given as $(a,0).$ We take locus of those which are variable. When we take the trajectory of the path of a variable point then it is called its locus. If you take $a$ to be variable then the locus of the centre is the $X$-axis (if you allow $a$ to take $0$). Otherwise it will be $X$ axis $\setminus \{0 \}.$

Comment: Hint : $$\dfrac hk=?$$

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

Look at the problem geometrically. For each point ${\bf z}\ne(0,0)$ on the given circle you get the point ${1\over2}{\bf z}$ as a point of your locus.